Is it possible to adjust QlineEdit icon spacing?
I'm planning to use a QLineEdit with three actions added via addAction().
Easy enough and it looks like this: (squares as icons for the example)

But a minor annoyance is that I find the spacing between the icons a bit too large.
Is it possible to adjust this spacing? QLineEdit doesn't seem to have an accessible layout where you could set the spacing.

Those are actually QToolButtons. You could try to subclass QLineEdit and update their geometries on resizeEvent()

@musicamante, I kind of assumed that resizing the Toolbuttons would not change the spacing. Do you think it will?

You'd need to call setGeometry(). I'd call the base resizeEvent(), then get the geometry of all buttons, translate them using the rightmost as a reference, and call setGeometry() with the new rects.

@musicamante, I was able to make it work well enough with calling setGeometry on the buttons from a reimplemented resizeEvent. But I see you've been keeping yourself busy finding a really proper solution.

Yeah, in reality I realized that that spacing often annoyed me, and I decided to consider its implementation more thoroughly. setGeometry() alone may not be enough, as they are not considered for effective text margins computation.

Actions shown in QLineEdit (including that used for the "clear button") are implemented privately.
The addAction(<action|icon>, position) is an overload of QWidget::addAction() that, after calling the base implementation, also creates an instance of a private QToolButton subclass (QLineEditIconButton).
The reasoning behind using QToolButton is that it provides immediate mouse interaction, and also has a strong relation with QActions (see QToolButton::setDefaultAction()).
Each button then follows common "side widgets parameters" that use hardcoded values:
QLineEditPrivate::SideWidgetParameters QLineEditPrivate::sideWidgetParameters() const
{
    Q_Q(const QLineEdit);
    SideWidgetParameters result;
    result.iconSize = q->style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_SmallIconSize, nullptr, q);
    result.margin = result.iconSize / 4;
    result.widgetWidth = result.iconSize + 6;
    result.widgetHeight = result.iconSize + 2;
    return result;
}

That is a lot of spacing and margins; it may be fine for relatively wide line edits or for systems using large icons and/or huge fonts, but also a considerable waste of space for most cases using more than one action (possibly including the clear button): even using a basic 16px icon size, this means that every 2 icons there is possibly enough space for another one.
In any case, once a new action is added, QLineEdit then lays out those "fake buttons" based on the above values, spacing them with the result.margin and considering the increased width.
Note that those buttons are not even drawn as real QToolButtons, as the private QLineEditIconButton subclass also overrides its own paintEvent(). In fact, it just draws the icon pixmap (using the enabled and pressed state of the action/button) within the QToolButton rect().
Luckily, painting and mouse interaction are always based on the button geometry, meaning that we can programmatically change their geometry once they've been set (and still have full functionality), which happens when:

a new action is added (which automatically creates the related button);
an existing action is removed/deleted;
the widget is resized;
the layoutDirection changes;

For very basic applications that only consider "trailing actions", we could just consider the first three cases above (and left-to-right text), then arbitrarily update the geometries of the tool buttons based on assumed sizes and positions; that may not be sufficient, though, because there can be actions on both sides, and the layout direction also inverts the position (and order) of those actions.
Also, QLineEdit considers the effective text margins (the "bounding rectangle" in which text is actually shown and can be interacted with) based on the above "side widget parameters", meaning that once we've reduced the size and/or spacing between the buttons, we're still left out with the same, possibly small, horizontal space left for displayed text and cursor movement.
This means that we need to keep track of the position of each action (leading or trailing) and finally update the text margins with a further "private" implementation.
In the following example I'm showing a possible implementation of everything explained above, which should work fine in most cases. There may be some issues for actions that are explicitly hidden (but I'll check that later, as I'm under the impression that it could be a bug, see the note below[1]).
It should also work fine for both PyQt6 and PySide6, as well as PyQt5 and PySide2 (except for the enum namespaces for older PyQt5 versions and PySide2).
class CustomLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__textMargins = QMargins()
        self.__iconMargins = QMargins()

        self.__leadingActions = set()
        self.__trailingActions = set()
        self.__actions = {
            QLineEdit.ActionPosition.LeadingPosition: self.__leadingActions, 
            QLineEdit.ActionPosition.TrailingPosition: self.__trailingActions
        }

    def __updateGeometries(self):
        buttons = self.findChildren(QToolButton)
        if len(buttons) <= 1:
            return

        iconSize = self.style().pixelMetric(
            QStyle.PixelMetric.PM_SmallIconSize, None, self)
        iconMargin = max(1, iconSize // 8)
        btnWidth = iconSize + 2

        leading = []
        trailing = []
        for button in buttons:
            if button.defaultAction() in self.__leadingActions:
                leading.append(button)
            else:
                trailing.append(button)

        if self.layoutDirection() == Qt.LayoutDirection.RightToLeft:
            leading, trailing = trailing, leading

        if leading:
            if len(leading) > 1:
                leading.sort(key=lambda b: b.x())
                lastGeo = leading[-1].geometry()
                it = iter(leading)
                prev = None
                while True:
                    button = next(it, None)
                    if not button:
                        break
                    geo = button.geometry()
                    geo.setWidth(btnWidth)
                    if prev:
                        geo.moveLeft(prev.x() + prev.width() + iconMargin)
                    button.setGeometry(geo)
                    prev = button
            else:
                button = leading[0]
                lastGeo = button.geometry()
                geo = button.geometry()
                geo.setWidth(btnWidth)
                button.setGeometry(geo)
            left = geo.right() - lastGeo.right()
        else:
            left = 0

        if trailing:
            if len(trailing) > 1:
                trailing.sort(key=lambda b: -b.x())
                lastGeo = trailing[-1].geometry()
                it = iter(trailing)
                prev = None
                while True:
                    button = next(it, None)
                    if not button:
                        break
                    geo = button.geometry()
                    if prev:
                        geo.setWidth(btnWidth)
                        geo.moveRight(prev.x() - iconMargin)
                    else:
                        geo.setLeft(geo.right() - btnWidth + 1)
                    button.setGeometry(geo)
                    prev = button
            else:
                button = trailing[0]
                lastGeo = button.geometry()
                geo = button.geometry()
                geo.setLeft(geo.right() - btnWidth + 1)
                button.setGeometry(geo)
            right = lastGeo.x() - geo.x()
        else:
            right = 0

        self.__iconMargins = QMargins(left, 0, right, 0)
        super().setTextMargins(self.__textMargins + self.__iconMargins)

    # Note that these are NOT "real overrides"
    def addAction(self, *args):
        if len(args) != 2:
            # possibly, the default QWidget::addAction()
            super().addAction(*args)
            return

        arg, position = args
        if isinstance(arg, QAction):
            action = arg
            # check if the action already exists in a different position, and 
            # eventually remove it from the related set
            if (
                position == QLineEdit.ActionPosition.LeadingPosition
                and action in self.__trailingActions
            ):
                self.__trailingActions.discard(action)
            elif action in self.__leadingActions:
                self.__leadingActions.discard(action)
            super().addAction(action, position)
            self.__actions[position].add(action)
            # addAction(action, position) is "void" and returns None
            return

        action = super().addAction(arg, position)
        self.__actions[position].add(action)
        # for compliance with the default addAction() behavior
        return action

    def textMargins(self):
        return QMargins(self.__textMargins)

    def setTextMargins(self, *args):
        self.__textMargins = QMargins(*args)
        super().setTextMargins(self.__textMargins + self.__iconMargins)

    # Common event overrides
    def actionEvent(self, event):
        super().actionEvent(event)
        if event.type() == event.Type.ActionRemoved:
            # this should take care of actions that are being deleted, even
            # indirectly (eg. their parent is being destroyed)
            action = event.action()
            if action in self.__leadingActions:
                self.__leadingActions.discard(action)
            elif action in self.__trailingActions:
                self.__trailingActions.discard(action)
            else:
                return
            self.__updateGeometries()

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        super().changeEvent(event)
        if event.type() == event.Type.LayoutDirectionChange:
            self.__updateGeometries()

    def childEvent(self, event):
        super().childEvent(event)
        if (
            event.polished() 
            and isinstance(event.child(), QToolButton)
            # the following is optional and the name may change in the future
            and event.child().metaObject().className() == 'QLineEditIconButton'
        ):
            self.__updateGeometries()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.__updateGeometries()

And here is an example code that creates two line edits with similar functionalities (two undo/redo actions and clear button), in order to compare the differences in layouts.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    test = QWidget()
    layout = QFormLayout(test)

    undoIcon = QIcon.fromTheme('edit-undo')
    if undoIcon.isNull():
        undoIcon = app.style().standardIcon(
            QStyle.StandardPixmap.SP_ArrowLeft)
    redoIcon = QIcon.fromTheme('edit-redo')
    if redoIcon.isNull():
        redoIcon = app.style().standardIcon(
            QStyle.StandardPixmap.SP_ArrowRight)

    def makeLineEdit(cls):
        def checkUndoRedo():
            undoAction.setEnabled(widget.isUndoAvailable())
            redoAction.setEnabled(widget.isRedoAvailable())

        widget = cls()
        widget.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        undoAction = QAction(undoIcon, 'Undo', widget, enabled=False)
        redoAction = QAction(redoIcon, 'Redo', widget, enabled=False)
        widget.addAction(redoAction, QLineEdit.ActionPosition.TrailingPosition)
        widget.addAction(undoAction, QLineEdit.ActionPosition.TrailingPosition)

        undoAction.triggered.connect(widget.undo)
        redoAction.triggered.connect(widget.redo)
        widget.textChanged.connect(checkUndoRedo)
        return widget

    layout.addRow('Standard QLineEdit:', makeLineEdit(QLineEdit))
    layout.addRow('Custom QLineEdit:', makeLineEdit(CustomLineEdit))

    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

Here is the result:

[1]: there could be some inconsistencies with QEvent.Type.ActionChanged for actionEvent() (which is received first by the private QLineEditIconButton) when the visibility of an action changes at runtime and after __updateGeometries() has been already called following the other events, which may reset the text margins. I will do further investigation, as I believe it as a symptom of a bug, other than a possible inconsistency in the behavior of the latest Qt versions.
[2]: I've not tested this on many styles, nor with complex selections or drag&drop; feel free to leave a comment about these aspects or related unexpected behavior.

Can you explain why the overrides aren't "real"?

@mahkitah With "true" override I mean a function that could theoretically be called by Qt itself (eg. paintEvent()) and is also explicitly declared as virtual in the C++ API, meaning that the python override would be called. I don't remember any part of Qt that directly calls addAction() (nor uses the QLineEdit text margins functions), but, in case there are, the "override" above wouldn't be called. This is the case, for example, of initStyleOption() of widgets such as QPushButton (unlike delegates): even if it's "overridden" in Python, it will never be called by Qt.

One little issue I've noticed. When you have the clearbutton enabled and set the layoutdirection RightToLeft, when there's no text (so also no clearbutton) the cursor is at the right edge of the trailing icon (which is left now) without a gap. This is a kind of unnatural situation with the text still being left to right. Also, for me the clearbutton is always the innermost icon which isn't the case in the example screenshot above.

I also found an off-by-one in the spacing of the trailing icons. This is caused by moveRight(x) which I found doesn't move the right edge to x (as documented), but it moves the rect so that right() returns x. And since right() is off-by-one for 'historical reasons', the move is also off.

@mahkitah I noted inconsistencies with the clear button position and text margins too, but some of them also existed in the default behavior and based on initial research partially related to the issue with hidden actions noted above. The external position of the clear button was caused by the older Qt version I used for the screenshot, they changed in later versions probably because it was counter intuitive to have the remaining actions moving once the text is cleared (I personally find it annoying that the button is only visible when text exists, and I normally prefer to always show it and »

» just enable/disable when necessary). Thanks for the note about the 1 pixel offset, I used in an early version but I probably forgot it when I revised the code to address the geometry change of the "first" button. I'll check and fix it once I'll end my research about the visibility/positioning issues above.
